# TemplateDoesNotExist at / (home.html)

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm working on an example Placeholder Image Server. This uses a single file approach, so urls, views, settings, are all in just one file called `placeholder.py`.

Each time I try visiting `http://localhost:8000` (the homepage), I get `TemplateDoesNotExist at /` thrown at me. I can't figure out what's wrong. Below is the project structure:

1. /placeholder

   - placeholder.py
   - /templates

     - home.html
   - /static

     - style.css

Here's the content of each file:

`placeholder.py`

```
import hashlib
import os
import sys
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from django.conf import settings
from django import forms
from django.urls import path, reverse
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.http import etag
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

# settings likely to change between environments
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', 'on') == 'on'
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'soj-4^4nho$ifsxsoi1+a8&6o&dya)tcivwcg9g_82&8sg*q^9')
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS', 'localhost').split(',')

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# settings
settings.configure(
    DEBUG=DEBUG,
    SECRET_KEY=SECRET_KEY,
    ALLOWED_HOSTS=ALLOWED_HOSTS,
    ROOT_URLCONF=__name__,
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES=(
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ),
    INSTALLED_APPS=(
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ),
    TEMPLATES=[
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        }
    ],
    STATICFILES_DIRS=(
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    ),
    STATIC_URL='/static/',
)

# simple form to validate the height and width of an image
class ImageForm(forms.Form):
    '''form to validate requested placeholder image'''
    width = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=2000)
    height = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=2000)

    def generate(self, image_format='PNG'):
        '''generate an image of the given type and return as raw bytes'''
        width = self.cleaned_data['width']
        height = self.cleaned_data['height']
        key = '{}.{}.{}'.format(width, height, image_format)
        content = cache.get(key)
        if content is None:    
            image = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
            text = '{} x {}'.format(width, height)
            textwidth, textheight = draw.textsize(text)
            if textwidth < width and textheight < height:
                texttop = (height - textheight) // 2
                textleft = (width - textwidth) // 2
                draw.text((textleft, texttop), text, fill=(255, 255, 255))
            content = BytesIO()
            image.save(content, image_format)
            content.seek(0)
            cache.set(key, content, 60 * 60)
        return content

# for client-side caching
def generate_etag(request, width, height):
    content = 'Placeholder: {0} x {1}'.format(width, height)
    return hashlib.sha1(content.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

# views
def index(request):
    example = reverse('placeholder', kwargs={'width':50, 'height':50})
    context = {
        'example' : request.build_absolute_uri(example)
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)

@etag(generate_etag) # decorator for client-side caching
def placeholder(request, width, height):
    form = ImageForm({'width':width, 'height':height})
    if form.is_valid():
        image = form.generate()
        return HttpResponse(image, content_type='image/png')
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('<h1>Invalid Image Request!</h1>')

# the url
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='homepage'),
    path('image/<int:width>x<int:height>', placeholder, name='placeholder'),
]

# wsgi application
application = get_wsgi_application()

# relevant part from manage.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

`home.html`

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Demo Placeholder Images</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Demo Placeholder Images</h1>
        <p>This server can be used for serving placeholder images for any webpage.</p>
        <p>To request a placeholder image of a given width and height simply include
            an image with the source pointing to <b>/placeholder/&lt;width&gt;x
                &lt;height&gt;/</b> on this server such as:
        </p>
        <pre>&lt;img src="{{ example }}"&gt;</pre>
        <h2>Examples</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><img src="{% url 'placeholder' width=50 height=50 %}"></li>
            <li><img src="{% url 'placeholder' width=100 height=50 %}"></li>
            <li><img src="{% url 'placeholder' width=50 height=100 %}"></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Create templates folder inside the project, Not in app

Comment: @Deependra Singh There are no apps in the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The value of `'DIRS'` in the `TEMPLATES` setting is meant to be a list. Here's what I mean:

```
...
TEMPLATES=[
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
    }
],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your BASE_DIR is incorrect. Because you have one simple flat file, and templates and static files are in subdirectories at the same level, you only need to go to the current directory, not the parent. So it should be:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```